# Where to find the hostname and port to SAS hosted servers for SWAT

Tags: python, sas

I just made an OnDemand for Academics account to use sas on Python and I couldn't find my hostname and port to create a connection to the CAS server.

I tried to use this, but I get an error:

```
conn = swat.CAS('odaws01-euw1.oda.sas.com', 5570)
```

> ERROR: The TCP/IP tcpSockConnect support routine failed with error
> 10060 (The connection has timed out.). ERROR: Failed to connect to
> host 'odaws01-euw1.oda.sas.com', port 5570.

Comment: Note SASPy is for 9.4 and SWAT is for Viya.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the CAS server is available for connections over the internet, you can find out the options for the server and port from the following SAS code run on the server (in SAS StudioV):

```
proc options group=cas;
run;
```

That will show the `cashost` and `carport` options values.  You could also look those up directly.

These are also visible as macro variables in a StudioV session, if you run

```
%put _all_;
```

It is possible that the CAS server is *not* exposed to the internet, though, for ODA.  The micro services server is often segregated from the CAS server in larger SAS Via installations, and the CAS server might only accept connections over 5570 (or any other port) from the micro services servers (or from servers on the datacenter's network).

It does seem like for some demos this is restricted, and for others it is not restricted; see [this post on SAS Communities for more details](https://communities.sas.com/t5/Developers/Unable-to-connect-to-CAS-Server-using-SWAT-and-Python-Client/td-p/538358).  You might consider asking about SAS ODA directly there (in the forum for ODA topics); they may be able to help you.